# I'm unable to load a new URL into a UIWebView from another class when the timer runs out iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, loading

I have a class `LiveView` where I have declared a UIWebView `myWebView`. It loads fine whilst I'm in the same class, with a click of a button I can change the URL to a different one, no problem. 
I have another class called `LoopCam` where in a text field the user can input a number of seconds after which the URL should change to another. 
I've created the loop correctly so after X amount of seconds a different URL should load. I've used NSLog and it works correctly so after X amount of seconds the NSLog prints out the new URL correctly to the console BUT if use:
`[_liveView.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]]];`in order to load the new URL (example.com), it wont load.

I did create an instance of a class in the LoopCam class like so: `LiveView * _liveView;` and imported the header `#import "LiveView.h"` and I've synthesized it in `LoopCam.m` like so: `@synthesize liveView  = _liveView;`
Is there a way to load a new URL in a UIWebView from another class without having to press a button? 
PS. even pressing a button the new URL wont load. 
Thanks

Comment: Is `myWebView` synthesized etc correctly? Do `NSLog(@"%@", _liveView.myWebView);`

Comment: Try to alloc webview every time when ever new url will come then u allocate webview.

Comment: When I do: <code>NSLog(@"%@", _liveView.myWebView);</code>   in ViewDidLoad in LoopCam I get a (null) response @jjv360

Comment: Then check that you are initializing `_liveView.myWebView` somewhere, check that it's either not synthesized or if it is you're using the right variable, and check that `_liveView` is also initialized properly, ie do `NSLog(@"%@", _liveView);`

Answer (score 1):

"I did create an instance of a class in the LoopCam class like so: LiveView * _liveView;"

This does not create an instance, this just creates the property that will point to one. You need to get a reference to the instance of LiveView that you already have. How you do that depends on how you got from LiveView to LoopCam. For instance, if you get to LoopCam from LiveView via a push, then you would set the property _liveView to self before doing the push. With a push segue, you would implement prepareForSegue:sender: like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoToLoop"]){
       LoopCam *loopCam = (LoopCam *)segue.destinationViewController;
       loopCam._liveView = self;
    }
}
```

You need to set the identifier for the segue in IB (I call it GoToLoop here).

Comment: I'am getting from LiveView to LoopCam with a push as you said. So how would I set the property to self?

Comment: @Dashony, how are you pushing -- in code with pushViewController:animated: or with a segue?

Comment: With the segue. There are a series of view controllers and first 4 are under class LiveView and the fifth one is LoopCam. The transition is done with a button as push segue. Not with code just in the Storyboard . @rdelmar

Comment: Your code above goes in LoopCam class I guess. Correct? In LoopCam class Xcode is suggesting to change loopCam._liveView = self; to loopCam.liveView = self; and if I do this it highlights "self" and gives me that yellow error "incompatible pointer types assigning to LiveView* from LoopCam*const_strong"

Comment: @Dashony, no it goes in LiveView. Whichever controller the segue is coming from.

Comment: So in LiveView.h I need to declare LoopCam *_loopCam; and also the property @property (nonatomic, retain) LoopCam *loopCam; ? otherwise it says undeclared loopCam.

Comment: @Dashony, No, you need to import LoopCam into the LiveView controller's .m file. You don't need to declare any property for LoopCam in LiveView, you're just creating a local variable in the code I posted.

Comment: I did import LoopCam.h into LiveView.m but the code above gives me errors about the last "self" @rdlmar

Comment: first it asks me to remove the _(underscore) and to make it liveView and then I get an error about "self"  "incompatible pointer types assigning to LiveView* from LoopCam*const_strong" @rdlmar

Comment: @Dashony, it's not clear to me how you declared liveView in LoopView.h You should do it like this '@property (strong,nonatomic) LoopView *loopView; 'Then, don't synthesize it in the .m, that's done automatically for you now (it creates an instance variable called _liveView, but the property is liveView).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25169/discussion-between-dashony-and-rdelmar)